# c++ how to destroy namespaced object

Tags: c++, namespaces, destructor

I've got a std::stringstream pointer:

```
std::stringstream *stream;
```

and I create an intance:

```
stream = new std::stringstream();
```

How can I call the stringstream destructor? The following fails:

```
stream->~stringstream();
```

with the error: *expected class-name before ‘(’ token*. If it's possible, I'd like not to use *using namespace std*. Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Why won't you use `delete stream;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with namespaces. You simply call `delete` on the pointer:

```
delete stream;
```

But why do you need a pointer in the first place? If you allocate an object with automatic storage, it will be destroyed on exiting the scope it was declared in:

```
{
  std::stringstream stream;
} // stream is destroyed on exiting scope.
```

Comment: I use a pointer because the string stream is a class member and I create the object in upper class constructor and destroy inside its destructor (it's a composition).

Comment: then you create with `new` and destroy with `delete`, you do not need to manually call a destructor. And instead of using `delete` you should store the object in a smart pointer. Or don't use a pointer, as juanchopanza suggests

Comment: -1 This does not address how to call explicit destructors of namespace objects, which is part of OP's problem. Instead tells OP to do something else which is a workaround without addressing the original syntax error. Not good for researchers like myself trying to figure out how to call destructors explicitly for objects defined in `std` namespace.

Comment: @AntiElephant That isn't OP's problem. Their problem is they don't know how to end the life of objects. You're projecting. OP selected this answer for a reason.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. There are plenty of cases where explicitly calling the destructor is needed, such as when using discriminated unions. In fact, I have this same problem and I yet again stumble upon the "classic Stackoverflow answer".

Comment: @Midnightas It seems this isn't one of those cases. All that is desired here is that the destructor of an object gets called at some point. OP didn't know how to do it, this answer tells him how to.

Answer (score 3):

Pure syntax:

```
{
  using std::stringstream; // make the using as local as possible
  stream->~stringstream(); // without using, impossible
                           // note: this destroys the stream but 
                           //       doesn't free the memory
}
```

However, I can't think of any sensible use. I would rather call delete in this case, use `unique_ptr` or, even better, use automatic storage.

An explicit destructor call can be useful in allocators, but they are templated so there is no need for usings.

Comment: so it's better to use 'delete xxx' instead of 'xxx->~Class();' always?

Comment: it's not just better, it's essential if you created the object with `new`, otherwise you leak memory. But it's better to use a type that does the `delete` automatically

Answer (score 1):

The destructor will be called when you call `delete`. Like so:

```
delete stream;
```

The destructor is not meant to be called explicitly(though you can do that).